# Java-Cannot assign a value to final variable

Tags: java, static, final

```
class SomeClass{

    final static int temp;
    //temp=30;
    SomeClass(int a){
        System.out.println("here");
        temp=a;
    }
}

public class HelloWorld{

    public static void main(String args[]){

        SomeClass t1 = new SomeClass(10);
        SomeClass t2 = new SomeClass(20);

        System.out.println("t1:"+t1.temp);
        System.out.println("t2:"+t2.temp);
    }   
}
```

When I create object t2 of SomeClass I can't assign value 20 to it. What could be the reason here? I cannot understand the final static int type.

Comment: final means you can't assign a new value, it is like a constant. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_(Java)

Comment: because of you just defined as final this means you can assign variable at initialization time.

Comment: Maybe what you need is a non-static variable?

Comment: @Jens moreover, you *have to* assign an initial value to it: it cannot be left uninitialised. As it stands, this code won't compile because of that fact.

Comment: @AndyTurner Tell it to OP not me, I know what a final variable is

Answer (score 4):

You have to understand the two modifiers of the `temp` variable:

1. `static` means makes this a *class* variable so when you make the assignment in the object constructor, this is not a member of the object, but of the class. On the creation of `t2` you make a second assignment to the one and only class variable (not a member variable of the object).
2. `final` means that the variable can be assigned a value only once, and therefore the assignment in the construction of `t2` fails.

Do you intend for `temp` to be a member field of the object? Then remove `static`.

If you intend for `temp` to be a class variable that is reassigned? Then remove `final`.

Comment: Thanks!! I get it now.

Answer (score 1):

`static` means belonging at class level. And, `final` means you only can instantiate it once. So, when you use `final static`, you are instantiating it once when you create t1. Then, that cannot be reinitialized. See this [article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/final-static-variable-java/).

If you want to have a variable that cannot be changed at object level, remove `static`.

Answer (score 1):

when you define a variable final static, it means that you define it as a CONSTANT. Only one copy of variable exists which can’t be reinitialize.